# Two LINQ queries returning different data types

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I come to you in desperate need of help today. I have two tables named setup and channels which have a many-to-one relationship. Many channels belong to one setup. At any given time only one setup is active. I am trying to query my database and get only the channels belonging to the active setup. The query I have works, but returns an IEnumerable when I need a list. Yet I use a similar query to just get all the channels, and it returns a list. What can I do to get a list?

This query returns a List like I expect:

```
var q = (from a in DTE.channels
                     select a).ToList();
this.myChannels = new ObservableCollection<channel>(q);
```

This query, which provides the filtered data I want, returns an IEnumerable even though I call ToList(), and my ObservableCollection doesn't like IEnumerables:

```
var f = (DTE.setups.Where(m => m.CurrentSetup == true).Select(m => m.channels)).ToList();
this.myChannels = new ObservableCollection<channel>(f);
```

Any help is very, very appreciated. Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Are you sure that in the second query you are returning `List<channel>` and not `List<List<channel>>`? It looks like `m.channels` returns sub list, so if this is a case, then you might need to call `SelectMany` instead of `Select`

Comment: I just noticed your response. SelectMany worked! Thanks so much, Sergey. I don't know how to mark your response as the correct answer as I'm still new to StackOverflow. I think if you make it as a standalone comment I can do so though. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. I posted comment as standalone answer so you can mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer as it helped.
Your problem is that you have many to many relationship, so your `.Select(m => m.channels)` actually returns not `List<channel>`, but list of lists - `List<List<channel>>` as each record has own list, and it just returns these lists.

You just need to use `.SelectMany(m => m.channels).ToList()` instead `.Select` and `SelectMany` will get returned lists and will combine them into one list with all data. So you will have `List<channel>` as you need.